# Javascript - Multiple selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(document).on('click', '.SELECTOR1 OR #SELECTOR2', function(){
        // some code
});
```

What I want to achieve is to run some code if either one of the elements is clicked.

Comment: write like this  `'.SELECTOR1, #SELECTOR2'`   use coma

Answer (score 6):

The Sizzle selector engine that jQuery uses follows the same rules as CSS. With that in mind you can separate selectors using `,`:

```
$(document).on('click', '.SELECTOR1, #SELECTOR2', function(){
    // some code
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Simply use a comma to do that:

```
$(document).on('click', '.SELECTOR1, #SELECTOR2', function(){
        // some code
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/umhx89xw/).